# Does time expand along with space?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

The flat FRW metric is given by:

$$ds^2=-c^2dt^2+a(t)^2dr^2$$

If we take $dt=0$ then we get:

$$ds=a(t)\ dr$$

Thus we find that space expands.

If we take $ds=0$ to find the null geodesic followed by a light beam we get:

$$c\ dt=a(t)\ dr$$

Does this imply that cosmological time expands along with space?

Comment: Isn't the appropriate parallel to taking $dt = 0$, and concluding space is expanding, to take $dr = 0$ and then $ds^2 = -(cdt)^2$ and conclude that time is not expanding?

Comment: Duplicate of [Does cosmological time expand along with space?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116893/50583)

Comment: I believe this has been asked and answered here:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/83619/9887

Comment: @AlfredCentauri If one takes $dr=0$ then one just finds that proper time for a co-moving observer is the same as cosmological time. But a co-moving observer would be expanding with the Universe whereas we do not. He would be measuring time with an expanding light clock whereas our light clocks have a fixed length.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes. "Expansion" of time as you call it is the cosmological age. The "direction" of progression of the time defines cosmological arrow of time.

Comment: I'm arguing that *intervals* of cosmological time $c\ dt=a(t)dr$ expand in exactly the same way as intervals of space $ds=a(t)dr$.